# Convert PHP timestamp (with negative values) to MYSQL String with Formatted Date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a MYSQL database with a `VARCHAR` column called `date_of_item`.
In `date_of_item` are PHP timestamps generated with the `strtotime` function.
The PHP timestamps can either be `NULL` where no date is known, the *VARCHAR* value zero (unix epoch), or a positive/negative value indicating the date (some dates are before the epoch).

I want to change the value of the column to be simply a string representation of the date in the form `dd mmm yyyy` and treat it as a simple string (not all the dates are known exactly, some are just months and some are years... so a timestamp isn't really appropriate here).

I have looked at the `FROM_UNIXTIME` and `DATE_FORMAT` functions in SQL but they don't seem to be able to deal with the negative timestamps used in PHP.

Is there a way to `UPDATE` the table and change the value of the column taking into account the negative values of the PHP timestamps?

Pseudocode for the query would be something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE table_name SET date_of_item = FROM_UNIXTIME_WITH_NEGATIVE_DATES(date_of_item, "%d %b %Y") WHERE date_of_item IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Not a duplicate - there is more to this question (formatting the date, updating the original table in-place)

Comment: The core of the question is the same "Is there a way to ... change the value of the column taking into account the negative values of the PHP timestamps?"  The update-in-place is trivial.